# Реально ли провести XSS атаку если параметры через $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?

Tags: xss, уязвимости, php

На сайте вместо $_GET и $_POST используется explode и $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] с делением на секции посредством слешей, то есть url выглядят как site.com/parameter
такой своеобразный роутинг.

kjventura.com/2011/11/make-pretty-urls-with-php-url-routing/

Вместо site.com/tag.php?tag=title у меня site.com/tag/title. Надеюсь картина ясна. У меня же вопрос - как атаковать свой сайт, чтобы вылетел заветный алерт? Если сделать так:

```
site.com/tag/<script>alert()</script>
```

ноль реакции (порежет до следующего слеша), а может выкинуть серверную ошибку, если задекодить символами, опять ничего. Проверок нигде нет.
Помогите проверить скрипт, чтобы я знал как он атакуется (и сам исправлял проверками)

Comment: Если сайт ваш, то и код показать сможете ;)

Покажите это место где вы делаете explode, и проверяете какую страницу нужно отобразить :)

Comment: атака - это когда других пользователей атакуешь, а не себя самого.

Хотя даже в вашем странном случае, если всякую ересь в урл пихать, кроме выдачи "Страница не найдена" сайт ответить не должен ничем.

Comment: Юмор в том, что я пишу движок и учусь на ходу

Comment: для самостоятельного теста подойдет "атака" или какоето другое слово используется?

Comment: @thunder: «моделирование атаки»?

Comment: @VladD да, так можно)